# Difference between Abstract Data Type and Object

Tags: oop, language-agnostic, abstract-data-type

After reading this essay [OOP vs ADT](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~wcook/papers/OOPvsADT/CookOOPvsADT90.pdf), I have not quite well understood what is ADT all about and how it is connected with the interface concept. Can anyone explain the difference between these concepts with some code examples (Java or Scala would be great).

Comment: With ADTs, there is a single underlying representation type, and the operations belong to this type. In particular, individual values of an ADT need not carry any “vtables” or anything of the sort.

Comment: With objects, each object has a representation that is hidden from the rest of the program. Only the object's own methods can use this representation. In particular, it is impossible to use the internal representation of two or more objects simultaneously, even if the objects in question have the same static type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An abstract data type (ADT) is a mathematical model for a certain class of data structures that have similar behavior; or for certain data types of one or more programming languages that have similar semantics. An abstract data type is defined indirectly, only by the operations that may be performed on it and by mathematical constraints on the effects. Abstract datatype is not necessarily an OOP concept. It is an older term to describe the concepts of for example Stack and Queue in terms of their functionality, without describing the implementation.

From the link:- [AbstractDataTypes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type)

And an object is an istance of a class